# relationship graph generation

Tags: php, visualization, diagram

Is there any PHP library for generating relationship graph image?
I'd like to end up with something similar to 
http://www.augustana.ualberta.ca/~hackw/csc330/asn/augSchema.jpg
however I have all the data collected, including relations, so it's *only* about image generation...

Comment: Please don't write tags in titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PHP extension to the well known GraphViz package

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php

Comment: Any updates on this?  It hasn't been maintained since 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using the [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) as PEAR package [Image_GraphViz](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz).

On GraphViz' gallery page you can find nice [Examples](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php)